# Formula 1 rebus

Tags: mathematics, rebus

We're not talking about the motorsport, but about one of the most famous formulae in mathematics. It's also slightly rearranged and in a form of the rebus:
[image: No hint here]

**Hint**

> The answer is a single letter.

Comment: We are assuming log and ln are different, right?

Comment: @Sid Not really.

Comment: @Sid i believe it makes no difference here. The formula is universal if memory serves right.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Actually it makes difference. The base of the logarithm plays a significant role here.

Comment: I thought all logs of that value coincided with the same result. My bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> $\pi$

As observed by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil), the first half of the rebus is

> $\frac1i$

because

> January is the first month and an eye is the universal rebus of 'i'.

The image of the log represents

> logarithm

The thermometer and the coal represent

> $-1$

because

> 30.2° F is -1° C. The coal appearing beneath the line represents removing the 'C' because coal is carbon, whose elemental symbol is 'C'.

So the second part becomes

> $\log(-1)$

We know that

> $\log(-1) = i\pi$ from [Euler's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), $e^{iπ} + 1 = 0$,

so the second part is

> $i\pi$

Given the first part we end up with:

> $\frac{i\pi}i$

which is just

> $\pi$

Answer (score 4):

Currently unsure about the last part but the first part is

> $\frac1i \log \left(\frac{30.2?}{?}\right)$

because

> January is the first month and its over an eye and then there is a log and it then might be 30.2 because that is the number shown

---

EDIT:

Well done @Silenus, who worked out that

> The last part is -1 because 30.2 F is -1 C (Coal indicates C). This means that the equation is:

> $\frac1i \log (-1)$

Which is

> $\frac{i\pi}i$

Which is simply

> $\pi$

Comment: I am not sure what famous formula that represents...

Comment: It will end up as a value which will equate to a mathematical letter @Sid